# libuvc hydro catkin install fails

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a camera driver(any camera driver working) on a RADXA Rock board. Ubuntu raring - cheese works, but I can't get any ROS driver to make or work.

roslaunch uvc_camera uvc_camera.launch device:=/dev/video0

rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  couldn't query control

This is the catkin_make on the git clone of libuvc_camera.

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'libuvc_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(libuvc_ros/libuvc_camera)
CMake Error at libuvc_ros/libuvc_camera/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
By not providing "Findlibuvc.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libuvc", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libuvc" with any
of the following names:

```
libuvcConfig.cmake
libuvc-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "libuvc" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"libuvc_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "libuvc"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

this is the src directory:

rock@radxa:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  driver_common        image_common
common_msgs     dynamic_reconfigure  libuvc_ros

Thanks  This should be easier than playing 'driver roulette.'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134681/libuvc-hydro-catkin-install-fails/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The libuvc_camera package is available as part of the Hydro builds for ARM. you should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-libuvc-camera
```

For reference, the complete list of packages available for Hydro on ARM is available on [the status page](http://packages.namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1